# Excel VBA how to autosave for seperate users

Tags: excel, vba

We have three different users working that can update one excel document using dropbox. When any of these users clicks 'save' I would like the document to save in a shared dropbox folder. Each user has a different directory though on their computer to this dropbox folder though.

Here is my code so far, which is simply trying to save the copy in user1's directory - and if it gets a 1004 error, it tries user2's directory etc.

This seems to work, but I am still getting the msgbox at the end. How do I break these If statements to that it stops once it has managed to save a copy?

```
Sub Auto_Save()
Option Explicit

    Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Dim backupfolder As String

    On Error Resume Next

    user1 = "C:\Users\user1.si\Dropbox\Hub\"
    user2 = "C:\Users\user2\Dropbox\Hub Admin Folder\"
    user3 = "C:\Users\user3.si\Dropbox\Hub\"

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=user1 & ThisWorkbook.Name

    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=user2 & ThisWorkbook.Name
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=user3 & ThisWorkbook.Name
            If Err.Number = 1004 Then
                MsgBox "Could not save copy to your directory."
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The whole scenario does not make sense. If three users are working on the same workbook, you either have co-authoring enabled with Office 365, or they all work on a separate copy of the file (otherwise the file would be "locked for editing" to the other two). With the former, the file will be saved with version history, but remain in the same place. With the latter, they can't be editing the same file, so they all have their own copies and just save that copy wherever it lives with a simple Save command. What am I not getting?

Comment: amended to mention it is a shared dropbox file.

Comment: What is err.number after the save?  Has it stayed at 1004??  Maybe best to check the folder exists rather than the error.  Also, isnt this being called by the user using the sheet, so this can be done by code with no check, `if environ("username") = "User2" then strPath="C:\Users\user2\Dropbox\Hub Admin Folder\"`